# Como exibir locais próximos ao local atual do Dispositivo Android

Tags: android, google-maps, geolocalização

Antes de mais nada, eu já consigo pegar minha localização e exibir um Maker, mas eu tenho um web service que disponibiliza as coordenadas de uma rede de loja, no caso eu tenho que exibir os lojas mais próximas, minha duvida é se eu tiver uma lista de coordenadas como eu faço pra mostrar as mais próximas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tenta isso:

```
Location loc;
.....
float radius = 50.0; // Raio em metros.
float distance = loc.distanceTo(loc2); // recebe distância entre os dois pontos.
if (distance < radius) then inside. // verifica se tá dentro do raio estipulado.
```

[Resposta retirada dessa pergunta no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16894974/how-to-check-if-one-location-coordinates-fall-to-another-location-coordinates-ra)

Answer (score 1):

Aconselho você buscar a API do Google Maps:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/v1/hello-mapview?hl=pt-BR

Veja aqui uma outra referência para criar Marker:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/marker