# Estou desenvolvendo um App para android de uma rede de lojas

Tags: geolocalização, gps

Gostaria se saber como faço para pegar minha localização e exibir um Maker.

Depois goataria de criar um web service que disponibilize as coordenadas de uma rede de loja.

No caso eu tenho que exibir as lojas mais próximas da localizaçao do usuario. minha duvida é, teria como eu criar uma lista de coordenadas e mostrar as mais próximas da localização do cliente?

Comment: Você tem várias perguntas em uma só. Já fez alguma coisa? Resolva um problema de cada vez.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como exibir locais próximos ao local atual do Dispositivo Android](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/12857/como-exibir-locais-pr%c3%b3ximos-ao-local-atual-do-dispositivo-android)